# Memory leak in Rails 3.0.11 migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

A migration contains the following:

```
Service.find_by_sql("select 
                       service_id, 
                       registrations.regulator_given_id, 
                       registrations.regulator_id
                     from
                       registrations
                     order by
                       service_id, updated_at desc").each do |s|
  this_service_id = s["service_id"]
  if this_service_id != last_service_id
    Service.find(this_service_id).update_attributes!(:regulator_id => s["regulator_id"],                    
                   :regulator_given_id => s["regulator_given_id"])
    last_service_id = this_service_id
  end
end
```

and it is eating up memory, to the point where it will not run in the 512MB allowed in Heroku (the registrations table has 60,000 items).  Is there a known problem?  Workaround?  Fix in a later version of Rails?

Thanks in advance

Edit following request to clarify:
That is all the relevant source - the rest of the migration creates the two new columns that are being populated.  The situation is that I have data about services from multiple sources (regulators of the services) in the registrations table.  I have decided to 'promote' some of the data ([prime]regulator_id and [prime]regulator_given_key) into the services table for the prime regulators to speed up certain queries.

Comment: This isn't a memory leak, just a case that uses a lot of memory because everything before the `.each` causes Rails to load the 60K rows before it starts iterating.  Could you describe the problem you're trying to solve in words (edit the question, leave the source); I am sure there's a simple solution.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to copy two columns from `registrations` to `services`, assuming that in the existing `registrations` the `regulator_given_id` and `regulator_id` are the same for any given `service_id`.  (And I assume once this is done, you can remove those two columns from registrations and update the `:belongs_to` and `:has_many` model declarations).  If this is correct, then there's a simple solution.

Comment: Yes you are right.  And I have tried to think of a simple solution and failed to come up with one.  One thing that I didn't mention is that there are potentially multiple registrations for a service and I only want the most recent (just in case that has an impact on the brilliantly elegant shortcut you are just about to share with me).

Comment: You want brilliant and elegant, you got the wrong guy :-).  I'll try as an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This will load all 60000 items in one go and keep those 60000 AR objects around, which will consume a fair amount of memory. Rails does provide a `find_each` method for breaking down a query like that into chunks of 1000 objects at a time, but it doesn't allow you to specify an ordering as you do.

You're probably best off implementing your own paging scheme. Using limit/offset is a possibility however large OFFSET values are usually inefficient because the database server has to generate a bunch of results that it then discards.

An alternative is to add conditions to your query that ensures that you don't return already processed items, for example specifying that `service_id` be less than the previously returned values. This is more complicated if when compared in this matter some items are equal. With both of these paging type schemes you probably need to think about what happens if a row gets inserted into your registrations table while you are processing it (probably not a problem with migrations, assuming you run them with access to the site disabled)

Comment: While it is entirely possible that your strategies will help me get around the problem (and I may end up using them) I am fairly certain that there is a leak as the memory usage is progressive - it increases at 7MB or a so a second while it is running the update bit.

Answer (score 0):

(Note: OP reports this didn't work)

Try something like this:

```
previous = nil
Registration.select('service_id, regulator_id, regulator_given_id')
    .order('service_id, updated_at DESC')
    .each do |r|
  if previous != r.service_id
    service = Service.find r.service_id
    service.update_attributes(:regulator_id => r.regulator_id, :regulator_given_id => r.regulator_given_id)
    previous = r.service_id
  end
end
```

This is a kind of hacky way of getting the most recent record from `regulators` -- there's undoubtedly a better way to do it with `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` in SQL all in a single query, which would not only be a lot faster, but also more elegant.  But this is just a migration, right?  And I didn't promise elegant.  I also am not sure it will work and resolve the problem, but I *think* so :-)

The key change is that instead of using SQL, this uses AREL, meaning (I think) the update operation is performed once on each associated record *as AREL returns them*.  With SQL, you return them all and store in an array, then update them all.  I also don't think it's necessary to use the `.select(...)` clause.

Very interested in the result, so let me know if it works!

Comment: This looks identical to what I did, and it appears to perform identically and use as much memory.  I would guess there is a memory leak in update_attributes.  The site isn't exactly Twitter - I can copy the data down, run the migration and copy it back without anyone noticing if I chose my moment.

Comment: Hmmm, I guess I had a mistaken notion, but as you say, I was wrong.  There are `find_each` and `find_in_batches` methods http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/find_each that seem to intended to handle exactly the problem you're having.  I would be pretty surprised if `update_attributes` has a memory leak -- all it does is call `save` under the covers.  You might also look at `update_attribute` which only affects one column, but doesn't invoke validation callbacks, so doing two of those might actually be faster.